# Data in the receipt-data sometimes malformed

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm encountering a problem that I can't explain.

I provide an auto-renewing subscription in my app. I'm verifying the receipt data by sending it from my server to the app store.

I've tested it many times, and it has passed Apple review. Now my app is online and many users were able to subscribe. But from times to times, App Store give me back a 21002 status meaning that the data in the receipt-data property was malformed.

Here is an example of a receipt returning a 21002 status (decode with the `base64_decode` function of php) :

```
{
"pod"="0";
"purchase-info"=
 {


"app-item-id"="*********";
 "bvrs"="2.0";
 "purchase-date"="2013-07-31 23:49:36 Etc/GMT";
 "quantity"="1";
 "bid"="com.mycompany.myapp";
 "version-external-identifier"="********";
 "purchase-date-pst"="2013-07-31 16:49:36 America/Los_Angeles";
 "purchase-date-ms"="1375314576739";
 "unique-vendor-identifier"="*******-****-****-****-**********";
 "original-purchase-date-ms"="1375314576739";
 "original-transaction-id"="**********************";
 "item-id"="*********";
 "original-purchase-date-pst"="2013-07-31 16:49:36 America/Los_Angeles";
 "product-id"="com.mycompany.myapp.1Month";
 "transaction-id"="**********************";
 "original-purchase-date"="2013-07-31 23:49:36 Etc/GMT";
 "unique-identifier"="***********************************************";
 }
"signature"="ApdxJdtNwPU2rA5..........";
"signing-status"="0";
}
```

I've hidden some private info, but I've verified that the bvrs, item-id, transaction-id, bid are correct.

What to think about that? Is there a problem from Apple? Is it a hack attempt?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

When I see signature beginning with "ApdxJdtNwPU2rA5" I know that somebody is trying to "steal" our InApp. Apple is not paying us for these InApps.